# How to quit Vim quickfix?

Tags: vim

I know that when you run `:make` in Vim, you can use commands to go through each error like `:cn` and `:cp`.  However, I often find myself scrolling through warnings that I don't need to fix.  Is there a way to quit scrolling through the errors/warnings and resume editing?  (I have heard that you can set Vim to ignore warnings, but I've been told it's difficult so I'm looking for something easier).

Comment: I had this exact problem, This dark magic incantation scratched the itch: `autocmd FileType qf nnoremap :Sd<CR> :q<CR>:Sd<CR>`.  qf is the alias for the quickfix window.  `:Sd` is a custom command that toggle the quickfix menu, but it doesn't run in the quickfix filetype.  So intercept when the user bangs out the command to shut it down when inside the thing, and then send corrective remedial codes to quit, thus moving the cursor up top, then running :Sd, which closes the quickfix window and resume editing.  Don't be shy on the duct tape, it's the only thing holding the unit together.

Answer (score 83):

You can [close the quickfix window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:ccl) by running:

```
:ccl[ose]
```

If you want to [open the quickfix window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:cope) again (without having to run `:make`) you can run:

```
:cope[n]
```

Even if the quickfix window is not visible, you can still move forwards and backwards through the items in it with the commands `:cn` and `:cp`.

Personally, I find the `:cn` and `:cp` commands quite laborious to type, so I would recommend mapping them to something more convenient if you use them often. The [unimpaired](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) plugin provides [sensible mappings for moving through the quickfix list](http://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/a59a121ee6fd7337a5b3a115aba32de6fbf5f0b2/doc/unimpaired.txt#L30-33):

```
[q   :cprevious
]q   :cnext
[Q   :cfirst
]Q   :clast
```

Answer (score 16):

If quitting from that window is all you want you can do as suggested above

```
:ccl
```

or even simply

```
:q
```

in the errors window.
Or you can simply switch windows `ctrl-w+w ctrl-w+k`...

Answer (score 7):

> I often find myself scrolling through
>   warnings that I don't need to fix

Two solutions:

- The very very best solution: Set your compiler to the highest warning level and change 
  your code to get rid of all warnings.
- The very very worst solution: Set 'errorformat' so that warnings do not hit. See
  :help errorformat. How to do this is specific to your compiler output format.

> Is there a way to quit scrolling
>   through the errors/warnings and resume
>   editing?

Hmmm, maybe I get your question wrong but I would do it this way:
Open at least two windows. One shows the erros/warnings (quickfix window) and the
other shows your code. Just change focus from quickfix to code window in order
to continue typing code.